# PowerA Xbox series X/S won't work on my PC anymore

Tags: windows-11, device-manager, xbox-one

I recently tried to use my PowerA Spectra Infinity controller on my Windows 11 PC.

It works completely fine with my Xbox One, but when I try to use the controller on my PC, it won't show any lights on the controller. I tried using the Device Manager to check what's wrong. My PC did correctly find the controller, but it says this:

> This device cannot start. (Code 10)
> {Drive Not Ready}
> The drive is not ready for use; its door may be open. Please check drive %hs and make sure that a disk is inserted and that the drive door is closed.

I'm not sure why it says to check if the "drive door is closed".
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkypm.png)

Comment: It sounds like Windows believes the device is an optical drive.if you attach the controller through USB does it work properly

Comment: yes, I use it through USB, it recognizes it as an Xbox accessory. I'll show a screenshot right now.